# UITableView insertRows(at: indexPath) returns error of invalid number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` which is supposed to display an array of images.
The array is already filled before with 5 items and I need to use `insertRows` to fill my `tableView`. The problem is I receive the error below:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

My code is as below:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImagesTableViewCell
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(data: images[indexPath.row]!)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

I appreciate for any clue to solve this issue.

Comment: why are you calling insertRows in cellForRowAt? remove it and it will work.

Comment: My UITableView Cells jumps when trying to display the items while scrolling, and as i've been informed, i need to use insertRows instead of reloadData to solve this issue. Thats why i need to use insertRows.

Comment: Thats a different issue and insertRows is not a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath should contain only this much code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImagesTableViewCell
  cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(data: images[indexPath.row]!)
}
```

Remove insertRows from cellForRowAt and your code will work.

We call Insert rows function when we want to add a new element to tableView. You don't need it in your code as you already have a predefined image array.

Comment: You are right, it was like that before, but what if I want to use insertRows to fill the tableView?!